# Pi 3 WiFi drops

Tags: wifi

I use Raspbian Lite on my Pi 3 and have a problem where I can't access it remotely anymore - at some point. I use `wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` in my `/etc/network/interfaces` (I think). This should reconnect to WiFi if connection drops.

I can't look at it remotely and don't have a spare display for it anyway, so I just remove power cable, plug it in again and then it works again... for some time.

What can this be? I use a 2A wall adapter if that matters, really. I don't run it hot or do some heavy usage, just SSH and Apache2.

Comment: This is most often a power issue. The power supply says it outputs 2 Amps but that is not necessarily what it actually outputs. Second if you are using a separate cable to connect the power adapter and the Pi this can also cause insufficient voltage issues. I would measure the actual voltage at the board details of how to do this can be found here http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems

Comment: Is it known to behave like that with WiFi? There is no separate cable for the power supply, it's a 2A wall adapter that came with the Pi although not official as it's not 2.5A.

Comment: For my needs I thought 2A that this Pi 3 came with would be enough. Can it not rather be a configuration error?

Comment: If you are using `wpa-roam` you are **NOT** using the standard settings, so unless you list your files who knows. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Power supplies **DO NOT** output 2A, or anything else - they output voltage, and the load draws whatever current it requires. The troubleshooting link is very old, and modern Pi do not have these test points. Measure on pins 2, 6. See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)